# Spring MQ Consumer fault tolerance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a scenario to create fault tolerant MQ listener/consumer using java spring. We plan to deploy as a sprint boot MQ listener across multiple servers but only 1 should be able to consume it. So once it is down the other listener should start picking up the message. Please suggest how to achieve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JMS itself has no support for exclusive consumers; consult your JMS provider documentation to see if it provides such functionality as an extension.